# Installing node.js latest version on windows 10 throws an error: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I installed the latest version of node.js (enabling chocolatey option) and my command prompt displays this:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Mana\version'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: please uninstall node and reinstall it again

Answer (score -1):

Good Morning! My problem was fixed without any work.
Someone must have been working over night or it may just take a few hours to start working...